# Spark TextArea - Change part of text color

Tags: apache-flex, colors, styles, textarea, flex-spark

How can I change part of my text color in `spark.components.TextArea`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextArea can do that. Try this:

```
    var format:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
    format.color = 0x00ff00;            
    this.textarea.setFormatOfRange(format, startIndex, endIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, TextArea cannot do that. You should try RichText or some related component.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS02f7d8d4857b1677-165a04e1126951a2d98-7fca.html